# Replace period with colon after Chapter (and Section) in header using fancyhdr package

Tags: fancyhdr

I am using the book document class and I am using the fancyhdr package. In my header, I am using `\leftmark` on the even pages and `\rightmark` on the odd pages.

I would like `\leftmark` to display "Chapter 1: Chapter One" instead of "Chapter 1. Chapter One".

I would like `\rightmark` to display "Section 1: Section One" instead of "Section 1. Section One".

How can I do this? Here is my code. Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% Code for headers
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\textbf{\thepage}}
\fancyhead[CE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[CO]{Section \nouppercase{\rightmark}}

% Code to add page number on the right side of the footer on the chapter start page. 
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\textbf{\thepage}}
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section One}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine the mark by modifying relevant code from `book.cls`. For example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}% If you say a4paper, be sure to load geometry
% \usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% Code for headers
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\textbf{\thepage}}
\fancyhead[CE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[CO]{Section \nouppercase{\rightmark}}

% Code to add page number on the right side of the footer on the chapter start page.
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\textbf{\thepage}}
}
\makeatletter
\def\chaptermark#1{% from book.cls
      \markboth {\MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
          \if@mainmatter
            \@chapapp\ \thechapter: \ %
          \fi
        \fi
        #1}}{}}
\def\sectionmark#1{%
    \markright {\MakeUppercase{%
      \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@
        \thesection: \ %
      \fi
      #1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section One}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: chapter colon]

[image: section colon]

I'm not certain whether this is the best way to do it, however.

Comment: This works beautifully! Thank you very much!

Comment: @ShawnP No problem! And welcome ;).

Comment: I switched from the book class to the report class. How can I do this exact same thing? Thanks again!

Comment: @ShawnP Does it not work with `report`? Why did you switch?

Comment: It unfortunately does not work in report. I decided to switch because in the book class, a new chapter has to start on an odd page. This means in some instances, I might have a blank page before a new chapter and I don't want that.

Comment: @ShawnP Why not just use `\documentclass[openany]{book}` which allows chapters to start on any page, odd or even?

Comment: I actually found the answer to my question. Thanks again for your help!